# Cannot access closed file .When saving the file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am using jquery file upload plugin to upload file. so whenever one upload's a file 
i store that file in the session 
after storing the file in the session then i am retrieving the files from the session 
and storing it .When i try to save file which is more than 10 mb i get this error 
"Cannot access closed file"

Here is my c# code

```
file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + FolderName + "/"), strfilename));
```

In web config i have done this settings

```
<httpRuntime requestLengthDiskThreshold="15360" maxRequestLength="2147483647" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"/> 


<security> 
<requestFiltering> 
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" /> 
</requestFiltering> 
</security>
```

Can any one let me know where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please add settings in web.config code and  try.

`<system.web>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="20000" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" requestLengthDiskThreshold="8192"/>
</system.web>`
Please follow below link for reference

[File Upload Issue](http://forums.asp.net/post/3015230.aspx)

Comment: I have specified maxRequestLength=2147483647  i don't think that 's the issue. when i directly save the file into the server.it is getting saved but when i put the file into the session  then when i try to retrive it and save it that time it is not working it is throwing error

Comment: Now i am not storing the file in session. now  i am storing the file in temporary folder and then moving the file from temp folder to orginal folder

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problème, solved it with these 2 part of code in the web.Config, you can try :

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>


<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="10000" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying i will try it